# How to delete key from Map in Option Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Say i have case classes like this.

```
case class someClass0(content: someClass1)

case class someClass1(someContent: Option[Map[String, someClass2]])

case class someClass2(someKey: Array[Int])
```

I need to delete items in Map(which is immutable) by values.

This values i get through iteration.

```
  val keys_to_remove = new ListBuffer[String]()
  val keys_to_keep: List[Int] = List(100, 200)
  for (x <- keys_to_keep) {
    content.someContent.get.foreach {
      case (key: String, value: someClass2) => {
        if (!value.someKey.contains(x)) {
          keys_to_remove.append(key)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So, how to keep all the structure, and delete only needed items by key?

I was trying to change type of Map like

```
content.someContent.map(_.to(collection.mutable.Map))
```

But `content.someContent.get.remove(key)` is not working.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove all keys and keep structure

```
val someClass0_copy = someClass0.copy(content = Content(someContent = someClass0.content. someContent.map(_.removedAll(keysToRemove)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need mutability for that.

```
val keys_to_keep: List[String] = List("a", "b")

val res = content.someContent.map(
  _.filterKeys(k => !keys_to_keep.contains(k))
)
```

`filterKeys` filters a `Map` by testing each entries' key against a condition.

---

Of course, it is important to remember that you can't test `contains` on a `List[Int]` against `Strings`, as the result will always be false.

---

Furthermore, try looking up style-guides for Scala:

- Classes are usually named in upper camel case
- Values and variables are usually named in lower camel case

[Try it out](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/YMFz3cy/1)

Comment: I get Some(MapView(<not computed>)) ((((

Comment: @MakarNikitin This means that your `Map` is using the `MapView` implementation. This is a lazy implementation and will not yield results until you actually query them (e.g. using `.apply(key)`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `-` operator and foldLeft on keys to remove.

you are using `get` for get value, if you want do it safety, you need to use:

```
content.someContent.map(immutableMap => 
  keys_to_remove.foldLeft(immutableMap){
    (map, key) =>
      map - key
}).getOrElse(Map.empty[String, SomeClass2])
```

this works like in this example:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
val immutableMap = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4)
val keys_to_remove: ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer("b", "d")
println(immutableMap) // Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4)
val mapWithoutKeys = keys_to_remove.foldLeft(immutableMap){
  (map, key) =>
    map - key
}
println(mapWithoutKeys) //Map(a -> 1, c -> 3)
```

Comment: But i have not just Map but Option[Map].
I tried
`val mapWithoutKeys = keys_to_remove.foldLeft(content.someContent.get)
`
And get just `HashMap()`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it:

```
val optionalMap = someClass0.content.someContent.map {
  contentMap => contentMap - keyToBeRemoved
}

val originalStructure = someClass0.copy(content = SomeClass1(optionalMap))
```

Here's the [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/yJHvx7xsTm6q1nByIRDKIA)

Comment: I need not only filtered map, but also all parent structure.

Comment: @MakarNikitin I've updated my answer and also the link to Scastie.